# Resolve circular C++ template dependency

Tags: c++, templates, mutual-recursion

Suppose I have:

```
template<typename T>
class A { 
  typedef T t_type;
  void done_work();
};

template<typename T>
class B { 
  typedef T t_type;
  void do_work(){
    // adds work to an asynchronous event queue, eventually T.done_work() is called
  }
};

template<typename T>
class C { 
  typedef T t_type;
  void do_work(){
    // adds work to an asynchronous event queue, eventually T.done_work() is called
  }
};

typedef A<B<A > > a_with_b;
typedef A<C<A > > a_with_C;

void main(int argc, char** argv){
  a_with_b awb;
  a_with_c awc;
}
```

How do I resolve the typedef **a_with_b**?

I want to do this because A has a callback to B, and B has a callback to A. For example, A would call B.do_work(), and eventually B would call A.done_work(). Furthermore, these are each asynchronous calls, so I cannot simply call B.do_work() and wait until B returns "done" because A has other important work to do in the meantime.

The reason I can't just have A take a reference to B is because there can be other implementations that replace B, such as C.

Comment: I want them to depend on each other, but avoid the problem where it ends up being A<B<A<B<A<B<A<B ... > > ... > >.

Comment: Can you expand regarding the use-case? Possibly the underlying problem can be approached differently.

Comment: You don't need a *is-a* relationship to do what you describe. If A has a reference to B and B has a reference to A, you can easily do your callback.

Comment: It looks like `A` should be a template, but why should `B` and `C`?

Comment: The A is a template. It should be used with a parameter.

Comment: `typedef A<B<A > > a_with_b;` , B expects a type parameter but you're giving it template `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do this because A has a callback to B, and B has a callback to A. For example, A would call B.do_work(), and eventually B would call A.done_work().

Ideally you'd avoid the interdepencies in the first place, e.g.:

```
template<class T> struct A {
    std::function<void (T)> handler;
    void f(T) {}
    void work() { handler(T()); }
};
template<class T> struct B {
    std::function<void (T)> fn;
    void f(T) {}
    void work() { handler(T()); }
};

// ..
A<int> a;
B<int> b;
a.handler = std::bind(&B::f, &b);
b.handler = std::bind(&A::f, &a);
```

Comment: A separately defined completion handler works around the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! It should probably be `B::handler` instead of `B::fn`. Also I had to specify `A<int>::f` and `B<int>::f` in `bind`.

Answer (score 2):

Although I like the type-erasure `std::function` approach better in this case, **it is possible to make your original code work**.

Use a *template template parameter* to define `A`:

```
template<template<typename> typename T>
class A { 
  typedef T<A> t_type;
  void done_work();
};

template<typename T>
class B { 
  typedef T t_type;
  void do_work(){
    // adds work to an asynchronous event queue, eventually T.done_work() is called
  }
};

template<typename T>
class C { 
  typedef T t_type;
  void do_work(){
    // adds work to an asynchronous event queue, eventually T.done_work() is called
  }
};

typedef A<B> a_with_b;
typedef A<C> a_with_c;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  a_with_b awb;
  a_with_c awc;
}
```

Note that there are just a few changes. Now `A` takes a *template* instead of a *type*.

Also note that `B` and `C` is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

At least one of them must not be a template in your case.

Are you sure you need template in this case? If the two classes A and B or A and C are so tightly coupled that one explicitly references another, that seems clearly a case where templates should not be used on classes B and C, because you couldn't specialize any of those class with something else without breaking your whole callback magic.

By the way, a callback library like sigc++ might be what you need.

Comment: You **can**. See my answer.